# Export stl of a 3d graph, missing vertex parts

Tags: graphics3d, 3d-printing

[image]

[image]

Basically the pictures say it all. Why is the stl missing the vertex corners?
How to I get them to appear in STL? And BTW, how do I increase the detail(resolution) of the mesh generated in the STL?

Comment: Have you found the solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue with mine..

Comment: No, sorry. I've resorted to using other software.
https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3418180
But that doesn't solve this problem.